# Whether to say "parler comme d’une évidence de" or "parler comme une évidence de"?

Tags: prépositions

> J’ignore ce qu’il en est pour vous, mais je suis toujours profondément touché dès lors que j’entends un enfant parler **comme d’une évidence** de ce que sera son avenir.
>
> {vs}: J’ignore ce qu’il en est pour vous, mais je suis toujours profondément touché dès lors que j’entends un enfant parler **comme une évidence** de ce que sera son avenir.

Given the construction "parler ***de*** quelque chose", I wonder if it is necessary to include "de" even in the *fixed* expression "comme une évidence"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parler  being **intransitive**, it's definitely *comme d'une*.

With the transitive verb *dire* you would say *dire comme une évidence*.

Although *comme une évidence* is not an object complement,  the meaning is that the child speaks like the object was an evidence. Then we have to respect the grammatical logic.

Il parle comme *`s'il parlait`* d'une évidence

Il dit cela comme *`s'il disait`* une évidence .

Finally if it's not obvious, it's because a part of text is implied  (sous-entendu).

If you remove *de* then it's the evidence who speaks, which makes no sense : it would be the same construction  as  "*il parle comme Alone-Zee*" which is correct because the implied part is "*il parle comme Alone-Zee `parlerait`*" where Alone-Zee is the subject, not an object complement.

Answer (score 2):

Pour moi, c'est indubitablement  "comme d'une évidence". *Parler comme une évidence* signifie une toute autre chose...